# Merge and fill missing values based on multiple columns from another dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In order to merge two dataframes based on `year` and `city`, I want to fill missing values in **df1** `gdp_value` and `growth_rate` from the values in `gdp` and `rate` respectively from **df2**.

**df1**

```
   year city  gdp_value  growth_rate
0  2015   sh        NaN          NaN
1  2016   sh        NaN          NaN
2  2017   sh        NaN          NaN
3  2018   sh        NaN          NaN
4  2019   sh        NaN          NaN
5  2015   bj        7.0         0.01
6  2016   bj        3.0         0.03
7  2017   bj        2.0        -0.03
8  2018   bj        5.0         0.05
9  2019   bj        4.0         0.02
```

**df2**

```
   year city  gdp  rate
0  2015   sh    6  0.04
1  2016   sh    5  0.07
2  2017   sh    3 -0.03
3  2018   sh    6  0.05
4  2019   sh    4  0.02
```

I have tried with `pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['year', 'city'], how = 'left')` and I got:

```
   year city  gdp_value  growth_rate  gdp  rate
0  2015   sh        NaN          NaN  6.0  0.04
1  2016   sh        NaN          NaN  5.0  0.07
2  2017   sh        NaN          NaN  3.0 -0.03
3  2018   sh        NaN          NaN  6.0  0.05
4  2019   sh        NaN          NaN  4.0  0.02
5  2015   bj        7.0         0.01  NaN   NaN
6  2016   bj        3.0         0.03  NaN   NaN
7  2017   bj        2.0        -0.03  NaN   NaN
8  2018   bj        5.0         0.05  NaN   NaN
9  2019   bj        4.0         0.02  NaN   NaN
```

My desired output **df** is like this:

```
   year city  gdp_value  ratio_rate
0  2015   sh          6        0.04
1  2016   sh          5        0.07
2  2017   sh          3       -0.03
3  2018   sh          6        0.05
4  2019   sh          4        0.02
5  2015   bj          7        0.01
6  2016   bj          3        0.03
7  2017   bj          2       -0.03
8  2018   bj          5        0.05
9  2019   bj          4        0.02
```

Thanks for your help.

**Edited**, this solution seems works out, thanks:

```
df1 = df1.set_index(['year', 'city'])
df1.update(
    df2
    .set_index(['year', 'city'])\
    .rename(columns={'gdp':'gdp_value','rate':'growth_rate'})\
)
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the question you can also use update depending on your data and needs:

```
df1 = df1.set_index(['year', 'city'])
df1.update(
    df2
    .set_index(['year', 'city'])\
    .rename(columns={'gdp':'gdp_value','rate':'growth_rate'})\
)
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

---

One way is to use `combine_first` with `set_index` and column renaming:

```
df1.set_index(['year','city'])\
   .combine_first(df2.set_index(['year','city'])
                     .rename(columns={'gdp':'gdp_value','rate':'growth_rate'}))\
   .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   year city  gdp_value  growth_rate
0  2015   bj        7.0         0.01
1  2015   sh        6.0         0.04
2  2016   bj        3.0         0.03
3  2016   sh        5.0         0.07
4  2017   bj        2.0        -0.03
5  2017   sh        3.0        -0.03
6  2018   bj        5.0         0.05
7  2018   sh        6.0         0.05
8  2019   bj        4.0         0.02
9  2019   sh        4.0         0.02
```

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this problem, however the keys are to set_index and renaming the columns to match in each dataframe.  pandas does almost all of its operations using index alignment.

Comment: Soorry, I get `TypeError: Cannot compare type Period with type str` with real data

Comment: You need to have the dtypes of each columb to match also.  You have in one dataframe dtype time period and the other string.

Comment: Another issue, some other columns values in `df1` are becoming `NaN`s after `combine_first`.

Comment: Hrm....   That shouldn't happen.  Can you start a new question with a dataset that shows this behavior?

Comment: `update` function seems works, please check my edited question.